# python:AttributeError: 'GameStats' object has no attribute 'click_first'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm new on python and sorry

```
class GameStats():

    def __init__(self,ai_setting):
        self.ai_setting = ai_setting
        self.game_active = False
        self.reset_stats()
        self.click_first = True

    def reset_stats(self):
        if self.click_first:
            self.cobweb_left = self.ai_setting.web_limit
            self.click_first = False
        else:
            self.cobweb_left = self.ai_setting.web_limit+1
```

An error:AttributeError: 'GameStats' object has no attribute 'click_first'

I don't know why we can't use the value of self.click_first to test?
And I try to set a new variable just like this :

```
    click = self.click_first
    if click:
```

but it is wrong.
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I've switched 2 lines)

```
class GameStats():

    def __init__(self,ai_setting):
        self.ai_setting = ai_setting
        self.game_active = False
        self.click_first = True  <<<
        self.reset_stats()       <<<


    def reset_stats(self):
        if self.click_first:
            self.cobweb_left = self.ai_setting.web_limit
            self.click_first = False
        else:
            self.cobweb_left = self.ai_setting.web_limit+1
```

You call the method `reset_stats` *before* you define `self.click_first`, so defining it first will do the trick!

Comment: Because you need to tell Python what `self.click_first` is _before_ you check if it is True or False, otherwise Python doesn't know what it is!

Comment: Imagine I gave you a password then asked you to tell me the password, you could tell me because you already know what it is. But if I asked you what the password is _before_ I gave you it, you would have no idea! The same principle is applying here, you're asking Python if `self.click_first` is `True` or `False` _before_ telling it.

Comment: Oh Thanks!  I think I could think it more before I asked. emm... It is a so simple mistake. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem at all! That's what SO is for, a fresh set of eyes ;)